# Null Entry when passing data from Controller to a View Asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

in my controller i'm passing an id , Storing it in a ViewBag and then accessing it from the view and its giving a null entry

This is the controller :

```
  public ActionResult Create(int referenceID)
    {
       ViewBag.id = referenceID;
       //   ViewBag.type = type;
       // ViewBag.title = title;
        ViewBag.userID = new SelectList(db.UserProfiles, "userID", "firstName");
        return View();
    }
```

and this is how i'm accessing it from my view

```
        @{ Model.referenceID = ViewBag.id ; }
```

When i'm going to /Invitation/Create/1 
its giving me a null entry error.

Comment: First, what's the exact error? Second, why are you assigning to a Model property in the view? Does your model even have a referenceID property?

Comment: Yes the Model has the refernceID !! can i set it from the controller . Given that i have 2 create methods one for the get and post.

Comment: From what I see your Model == null. Your controller doesn't return anything. It should be return View(someViewModel)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code you provided, I'd say your Model is null, because your action doesn't pass anything to the view. Have you tried just showing the ViewBag.id on the page?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure that a routing path is configured for **/Invitation/Create/{id}** in your route table...in global.asax...i.e. in your the RegisterRoutes method of global.asax...make sure you have something like...

```
  // Invitation/Create
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Create Invitation",
            "Invitation/Create/{id}",
            new { controller = "Invitation", action = "Create", id= 0 }
        );
```

If referenceID in Create method is optional...you need to change the type of referenceID to int? (nullable int)...as shown below

```
public ActionResult Create(int? referenceID)
{
  // if referenceID is null then you may redirect the user to a view of your choice..
  // then what ever logic you may wanna write...
}
```

Hope this helps...

**Update:**

Can you try moving this map route code to be your first map route code?

Probably I should have read your question better...in your Create action method you are not returning any model to your view...and when you say Model.referenceId...there should be a model (that contains referenceID as a property) returned from your Create action method...which is missing in your case

Comment: Yeah the route is configured and the refernceID is not optional

Comment: @iyadalaqel can you post your view and routing code as well...I mean the whole routing code...? see my update as well...

Comment: sure ,, its the default i haven't changed it. and many other methods are using the same format Controller/Action/id and they are working

Comment: @iyadalaqel probably I should have read your question better...in your Create action method you are not returning any model to your view...and when you say Model.referenceId...there should be a model (that contains referenceID as a property) returned from your Create action method...